# "Nice" limits of sequences of smooth embeddings

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, limits-and-convergence, embeddings

Consider smooth embeddings of a manifold $M$ into some $\mathbb{R}^n$. If a sequence $f_k : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of such embeddings converges to some continuous function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then the following could happen:

1. $f$ might not be smooth on some subset $S \subset M$.
2. $f$ might not be injective on some subset $I \subset M$.

What conditions can we require of the convergence, and of $f$, so that $f$ is guaranteed to be "nice," in that only those two anomalies occur, and that $S$ and $I$ are nice too, perhaps finite disjoint unions of manifolds?

I'm looking for "typical" topologies people use that are widely used yet can guarantee niceness. I hope you can link me to some reference that explains how niceness is guaranteed.

Comment: You have some hidden assumptions here that you'll need to spell out if you want to avoid tautological answers.    What do you want "converge" to mean?  Pointwise?  That would be one answer.  Another answer would be that you are talking about sequences of functions in a certain function space.  If your function space is the space of smooth embeddings with the Whitney topology, then your limits are guaranteed to be nice since the topology is defined that way.   There's all kinds of intermediate assumptions you can make.

Comment: I realize that this is sort of subjective, but i was looking for "typical" notions of convergence that people use to guarantee nice limits. From your comment it seems that convergence in the Whitney topology might be a candidate but after some searching I can't see how niceness can be guaranteed - I'll edit the question to make my request more specific.

Comment: People choose the definition of convergence that is relevant to whatever it is they want to study.  There is no "typical" as far as I know, it depends on what you want to accomplish.